# PyQt5 doesn't save settings to ini files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qsettings

For an application i need to read/write values in .ini files. I use python3 with pyqt5 on windows7 and got this little example:

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

ini_str = """[mysection]
key0=value0
"""

with open("test.ini", "w") as fi:
    fi.write(ini_str)

inidict = {
    "mysection/key1" : "value1",
    "myothersection/key2" : "value2"
}


settings = QSettings("test.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

for k in settings.allKeys():
    print(k, settings.value(k))

for k in inidict.keys():
    settings.setValue(k, inidict[k])
```

reading values from my ini file works, but setting values, like in the second for loop, doesn't, values aren't saved to the ini file. So, i think i'm missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call the [`sync()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync) method so that the values are saved:

```
...

for k, v in inidict.items():
    settings.setValue(k, v)

settings.sync() # <---
```

The above is clearly indicated in the docs:

> [**void QSettings::sync()**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync)
>
> Writes any unsaved changes to permanent storage, and reloads any
>   settings that have been changed in the meantime by another
>   application.
>
> This function is called automatically from QSettings's destructor and
>   by the event loop at regular intervals, so you normally don't need to
>   call it yourself..

Of the previous thing it indicates that this method is in charge to keep the changes, and that if the event loop exists using some `QXXXAplication.exec_()` it is called in the destructor, but in your case there is not it, so you must call it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't read that part carefully enough! And i found many examples, where sync wasn't used - and now i guess there were event loops in that examples. Much clearer now!